# mysqli_fetch_assoc crash but mysqli_fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM) works

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to use the fetch_assoc or fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC), the program just crashes and doesn't display any error information(I do have changed error_reporting to E_ALL).But it works fine when using fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM) or fetch_row().
The weird thing is I can run my program on Wamp. But I cannot on the Apache+PHP+MYSQL environment installed manually.
so is this a PHP configuration problem or a MYSQL problem ?

```
 $studentId = $this->mydblink->real_escape_string($studentId);
    $result = $this->mydblink->query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE id = '$studentId'");
    if($result->num_rows <= 0){
        $result->free();
        return null;
    }
    else{
        $returnValue = array();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            array_push($returnValue,$row);
        }
        $result->free();
        return $returnValue;
    }
```

Comment: likely to be a php issue, what are the coulumn names its getting back ?

Comment: it would be interesting to know what the column names are. Maybe there's one that has a name that PHP can't cope with being an array subscript value. It seems unlikely, but that's the only explaination I can think of for this. Also, what happens if you change the `SELECT *` into a `SELECT field1, field2, etc, etc`. O wonder if that might help? (in any case, it's better practice to name your fields in the query rather than doing `*`, so it would be a good thing to do anyway)

Comment: Oh, and what PHP and MySQL versions are you running? That may be relevant. If they're not the latest releases, have you tried updating? Or checking [the release notes](http://uk.php.net/releases/index.php)? Finally, if you can reproduce this reliably on the latest PHP version, you should report it to the PHP bug tracker.

Comment: Only other thing I can think of would be if there are 2 column names which are numeric with a full stop in them. As I think php would try to truncate those to integer keys which might then be the same value. Ie, if you had a column 1.1 and a column 1.2 php would treat them both as 1.

Answer (score 0):

fetch_array() makes associative array in which there is a key and value.
fetch_assoc() only has value

You can also use fetch_object () that creates objects of your table name.

```
| id  |    category   |   name   |
----------------------------------
|  1  | 2, 5, 7, 28   |   Will   |
---------------------------------- 
|  2  | 2, 9, 15, 18  |   Drew   |
```

EXAMPLES:

```
$sql=mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT id, category, name FROM users");

$data=mysqli_fetch_array($sql);
// 0=>id, 1=>category, 2=>name
$data[1]; // is same like $data['category'];
$data['category'];

$data=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
$data['name'];

$data=mysqli_fetch_object($sql);
$data->name;
$data->category;
$data->id;
```